# How can I set tests to run one by one in one tab? selenium python

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, testcase

Is it possible to run tests one by one in one tab ? When i run my code both test runs at the same time

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

`from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from SlackHome import SlackHome
from mailPage import MailPage
from SlackApp import SlackMain
class SlackTest(unittest.TestCase):`


`@classmethod
def setUpClass(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/piotrkapczynski/PycharmProjects/teraz to bedzie dzialac/chromedriver')
    self.driver.get("https://slack.com/signin")
def test_logToSlack(self):
    driver = self.driver
    time.sleep(3)
    SlackH = SlackHome(driver)
    SlackH.sendDomain()
    SlackH.submitDomain()
    time.sleep(3)
    SlackH.loginInput()
    time.sleep(3)
    SlackH.passwordInput()
    SlackH.signIn()
    time.sleep(2)

def test_inviteUsers(self):
    driver = self.driver
    SlackA = SlackMain(driver)

    time.sleep(3)
    SlackA.inviteUser()
    SlackA.addNewUser('aaa')`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, tests are run independently so you can't keep state between different tests. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code):

> A new TestCase instance is created as a unique test fixture used to
>   execute each individual test method. Thus `setUp()`, `tearDown()`, and
>   `__init__()` will be called once per test.

What you could do is to define `test_logToSlack` as a normal method (so a method without the `test` prefix) instead and call it from `test_inviteUsers`.

Or if you want the code in `test_logToSlack` to be called for in every test in your test case, you can put it's code in a `setUp` method.